# 2009 dodge journey SXT aftermarket android head unit

Tags: dodge, head-unit, journey

im seeking help and advise on perfecting my android aftermarket head unit install. I say perfect because its currently installed but some electrical mods need to be made to stop it from draining my battery.

I have an android 2 din 7" aftermarket radio. its harness has the following power wires
- black (ground)
- yellow (12 v cons)
- red ( 12v acc)

I purchased a harness that fits my car perfectly (when it comes to harness-harness fitting). this harness has the following power cables
-yellow
-black

this kit brought a separate red cable for ACC and it has tripped me out to the point im confused. I have no idea where to put this red cable.

I had to wire the ACC red cable from the head unit harness to the yellow providing power 100% of the time, ignition on or off. and that's where problem comes in. I believe this unit doesn't fully power off when I press the off button and its more of a sleep mode. I need to find a way to only provide power with the ignition ACC red wire.

ive heard;
1- run red wire to a relay on the engine bay fuse box
2- use add a fuse toengine bay fuse box (IDK which fuse to use)
3- run red cable to battery red with a 15amp fuse
4- run red cable to internal fuse box ( cant find it in my car)

im really lost here guys, is there a wire on the factory harness that provides power only which ignition on? maybe one of the speakers or any other wire that I can use to tap into. ive searched the web for wiring diagrams and haven't found any. ive joined several forums for help and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

That red from your new unit is for ignition. We used orange for ignition but it could be anything by the time it gets to the head unit. You shouldn't have to run cable to connect it.

The harness adapter you got might be missing the ignition. Look up a pinout for the original harness and find the ignition line, splice that into your red. Alternatively look up a pinout for the original head unit and find where ignition is on the original harness.

IIRC sometimes we spelled "ignition" as "ACC".

Comment: Hey, yeah. The red is ignition. In order for me to make the head unit turn  on while the car is on I had to connect it to the constant since my harness doesn’t have an ignition wire/acc red etc. looking at the original harness that plugs into the factory radio I don’t see a red cable. I would need to start cutting into the original cable to see which one is for ignition. I looked for any Metra, scorche, xcorpion harnesses and they all have a harness with a separate red cable for ACC. Not one of them have the red cable already in ththe harness. @sam basso

Comment: dude, i dont have access to dealerconnect anymore so do yourself a favor and LOOK UP A PINOUT FOR THE OEM RADIO. i also cant do this for you because i dont know which one of any possible ones you have, and i cant see inside your IP. the pinout will indicate which pin on the radio side is for ignition AS WELL AS where and what color that wire is in the original harness.

Answer (score 1):

I owe this to anyone searching this forum site for answers. It turns out that the 2009 dodge journey radio acc ignition switch is controlled by some internal computer in the car called CAN BUS or DATA. you'll find different references for it but the 2 i just mentioned are it. What that means is that if you are installing aftermarket radio/head unit you wont get AMP power, antenna power, illumination or ignition cut off because they are all controlled by the CAN BUS and the factory harness doesnt have any wires for it.

you can wire the radio using metra harnesses but you'll have a hard time getting the things like ignition (red wire) &  Illumination (orange wire) to work.

The only way this will work (AS I JUST GOT IT WORKING) is by purchasing a "
C2R-CHY4"

link below:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Select-Chrysler-Dodge-Jeep-RAM-Radio-AMPLIFIED-VEHICLES-Wiring-Harness-/391269477897

It brings the harness and everything you need for the 2009-2010 Dodge journey sxt model.

took a long time to find the answers but i can ensure that this is all you need for installing an after market radio/head unit. without this, no matter how you wire the ACC red cable of your aftermarket harness either to fuse, or pink/white under the steering wheel or to a relay your cars battery will drain out after 2 days time.